# Proof integral operator is contraction map

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I have an operator $A: C[0, 1] \rightarrow C[0, 1]$, $$Ax(t) = \lambda \int_\limits{0}^{t} x(s) ds + 1,$$

I want to prove, that this operator is contraction map. I've already tried: $$||Ax - Ay||_{\infty} = \sup\limits_{s \in [0, 1]}|\lambda \int_\limits{0}^{t} x(s) - \lambda \int_\limits{0}^{t} y(s)| = \sup\limits_{s \in [0, 1]}\lambda | \int_\limits{0}^{t} (x(s) - y(s))|,$$

and I stuck at this moment, I can write inequality later, but I don't see how it can be helped.

I don't know to to eliminate the integral, if I do it I think, I solve this task.

Can anyone give me any clue?

Comment: The supremum should be taken with respect to $t.$ The difference of the integrals can be estimated by $\|x-y\|_\infty.$ so you get a contraction when $|\lambda|<1.$ As $\|A1-A0\|_\infty=|\lambda|$ the mapping is not a contraction for $\lambda|\ge 1.$